# How to "unpivot" a dataset: create multiple rows from a count variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Group1     2
Group2     5
Group3     1
etc.
```

But I want it to look like

```
 Group1
 Group1
 Group2
 Group2
 Group2
 Group2
 Group2
 Group3
```

In a sense, I want to "unpivot" or "uncount" the rows. Anyone know of an efficient way to do this in SAS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many ways... ETS has some useful tools for this if you're doing it in a complicated way (ETS = Time Series) with PROC EXPAND, but your sample dataset is easily done in the datastep.  Assuming `rowcount` is your variable with # of rows to produce:

```
data want;
 set have;
 do _n_ = 1 to rowcount;
  output;
 end;
 drop rowcount;
run;
```